# How can I keep the variable alive across the project globally?

Tags: java, page-objects, page-factory

I have a `BaseClass.java` which extends `PageObject.java` class i.e. `net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject;`

Then I have two Page classes `LoginPage.java` and `ProfilePage.java`, these two also extending the same `PageObject.java` class

I have a function in `BaseClass.java`:

```
public String createTestUser() {
        testUser = "test" + getTimeStamp() + "@demo.com";
        return testUser;
    }
```

Then I have function in `LoginPage.java` class where I test login feature using above created user, like this

```
public void doLogin() {
username.type(baseClass.createTestUser());
password.type("test123");
submitBtn.click();
  }
```

Now I have to verify whether correct user is logged in or not so I have a function in `ProfilePage.java` class

```
public boolean VerifySuccessfulLogin(){
   return verifyWebElementXpath("//div[contains(text(),'"+baseClass.createTestUser()+"')]");
}
```

This test failed. To fix this I tried:

I created a variable and function in `LoginPage.java` as

```
public String userForTesting = null;

public String getTestUser(){
    if(userForTesting==null ){
    userForTesting = baseClass.createTestUser();
    return userForTesting;
}
else {
    return userForTesting;
    }
}
```

Now I changed boolean function in `ProfilePage.java` as

```
public boolean VerifySuccessfulLogin(){
   return verifyWebElementXpath("//div[contains(text(),'"+loginPage.getTestUser()+"')]");
}
```

Still it is failing. It is generating new user for this boolean function. I am new to Java I have got few responses here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953005/how-to-pass-values-in-java-from-one-class-to-another but none worked.

What am I doing wrong? The `userForTesting` variable stays alive within `LoginPage.java` but after that it becomes `null` and so boolean function always gets newly created user.

**Update:**

public class BaseClass extends PageObject  {

```
private static BaseClass baseClassFinder = null;
```

public static BaseClass getInstance() {
        if (baseClassFinder== null)
            baseClassFinder= new BaseClass();
        return baseClassFinder;
    }

}

This is giving me error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.synthesizeAllParams(Executable.java:363)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.privateGetParameters(Executable.java:415)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getParameters(Executable.java:359)
    at net.thucydides.core.pages.Pages.lambda$hasDefaultConstructor$0(Pages.java:251)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(MatchOps.java:90)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:449)
    at net.thucydides.core.pages.Pages.hasDefaultConstructor(Pages.java:251)
    at net.thucydides.core.pages.Pages.createFromSimpleConstructor(Pages.java:232)
    at net.thucydides.core.pages.Pages.getCurrentPageOfType(Pages.java:204)
    at net.thucydides.core.pages.Pages.getPage(Pages.java:90)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.PageObjectDependencyInjector.instantiatePageObjectIfNotAssigned(PageObjectDependencyInjector.java:55)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.PageObjectDependencyInjector.injectDependenciesInto(PageObjectDependencyInjector.java:33)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.PageObjectDependencyInjector.instantiatePageObjectIfNotAssigned(PageObjectDependencyInjector.java:56)
```

Comment: why would you pollute your "Base class" just to create a random string('createTestUser')?

Comment: SInce everypage class is extending the baseclass, it will be easier to fetch testdata.

Comment: Yes, I see your point but I would prefer composition over inheritance to create an data object.

Comment: I prefer to distinguish between data and functionality.

Comment: **Yes, I see your point but I would prefer composition over inheritance to create an data object.** can you quote an example for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a static class called *TestData*, which will hold the test user.

```
public final class TestData {

    @Getter
    private static String testUser;

    public static void resetTestUser() {
        this.testUser = String.format("test%s@demo.com", getTimeStamp());
    }
}
```

And on BaseClass, you can have a @BeforeSuite method:

```
@BeforeSuite
public static void creatingUser() {
        TestData.resetTestUser();
}
```

This way, you can access the test user anywhere with `TestData.getTestUser();`
And if you need to reset it during the suite, you can call `TestData.resetTestUser();`

OBS: @Getter comes from [Lombok](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjRzrP__qDeAhUOaFAKHfjlBmkQFjAAegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojectlombok.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw2I1yZsNyZNywgaVKV4kHG0).

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you are making a call to getTestUser or createTestUser, it creates a new String.

I would suggest share the created test user across the test classes where you need the user. You might think of doing so by the TestClass's instance.

Below is a link of the same by Krishnan. A lot of times I refer this article.

https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/sharing-data-across-tests-in-different-testclasses/

Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: I have added my findings after testing you suggestion.

Comment: You have to use ITestContext in the test. Please have a look at the Consumer class.

Comment: I am using Junit with Jbehave.

Comment: I am not sure if junit has ITestContext. If you are not creating a lot of users at runtime, you can also think of having real usernames coming from some data provider and can access the same data in all the classes.